# Use switch external terminal in KDevelop (Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, ide, terminal, homebrew, kdevelop

I used homebrew to install KDevelop 4.6 on the Mac OS X Mavericks. Everything is functioning quite normally. Since the internal terminal does not support input, I tried to switch to an external terminal but failed.

Here are the default options:

```
konsole --noclose --workdir %workdir -e %exe
xterm -hold -e %exe
gnome-terminal -e %exe
```

None of them works and the error returned is "Could not start program <%exe> Make that the path is specified correctly"

Is there anyway to use xterm or Terminal.app or other thing as the external terminal? Thank you...